# How to run a python script in ANSYS such that after certain displacement threshold, the force becomes zero?

Tags: python, transient, ansys

I have edited a python script based on an answer on another question but it still does not seem to run. I have a force load which causes a displacement. I want that after a certain amount of displacement, the force becomes zero. This is the code that I have so far based on this previous problem [How to run a python script after every time step of a dynamic load in Ansys WB (transient analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70890724/how-to-run-a-python-script-after-every-time-step-of-a-dynamic-load-in-ansys-wb/73922653#73922653). I appreciate any advice and help:

```
model=ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model
firstAnalysis = model.Analyses[0]
solution = firstAnalysis.Solution

force_246=ExtAPI.DataModel.GetObjectById(246)

for loadstep in loadsteps:
    currentAnalysis = firstAnalysis.Duplicate()
    # Get the results from the last load step
    deformations = [item for item in solution.Children if item.GetType() == Ansys.ACT.Automation.Mechanical.Results.DeformationResults.DeformationResult]

    deformation1 = deformations.GetObjectById(53)

    for i in dis:
        if deformation1 >= 0.058:
            force_246.YComponent.Output.SetDiscreteValue(2.2, Quantity(0, "N"))
        


    solution = currentAnalysis.Solution

    solution.Solve(True)
```

Comment: is seems that you are missing imports or variable definitions, so i cannot reproduce the problem...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but I this will not work with every geometry. You don't apply the force directly on the target body but via a contact body:

1. Create a body on the area where you applied the force. Apply the force on thisbody
2. Connect the two bodies with a frictionless contact.
3. Fix the contact body with a translational joint. The x-direction of the joint should point in the same direction as the force.
4. Add a Stop to your joint. This way you limit the joint to the displacement you have in mind. This value can even be parameterized.

[image]

This will behave highly nonlinear, so expect convergence difficulties. Test this approach with a very small and simple subsection of your model.